# Form redirect (?)

Tags: forms, redirection

I' trying to build this kind of pages:

- one page for each taxonomy term with taxonomy info and all commerce products related to term

plus

- one 'products' page where users can click on a taxonomy image to view all the products in a box (loaded via ajax).

I have built taxonomy/term/* pages and the products page and they work fine but when I tried to add a product to cart (from taxonomy/term AND products pages.. ) drupal add the product to cart but always redirect me in the taxonomy/term page.

So I tried to setup a different form #redirect in [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) but it work in a strange way: when I call taxonomy/term page via ajax to include it in products page now drupal serve me the product page itself like there is a all times redirect from taxonomy/term page to products page.

```
$form['#redirect'] = drupal_goto('products');
```

If I write

```
$form['#redirect'] = 'products';
```

just do not redirect.

How can I achieve a right redirect?

I'm working in D7 with drupal commerce to manage e-commerce

Comment: You know [Working with #redirect](https://api.drupal.org/comment/18139#comment-18139)?

Comment: I missed comment https://api.drupal.org/comment/40338#comment-40338!! Thank you ^^

Comment: So if it works now, why not to post an answer? ;)

Comment: I needed to wait 2 days before answer my own question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if( startsWith($form_id, 'commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_') ){
    array_push($form['#submit'], '_mymodule_redirect_to_products_page');
  }
}

function  _mymodule_redirect_to_products_page(&$form, &$form_state){
  global $language ;
  $lang_name = $language->language ;

  $form_state['redirect'] = url('prodotti', array('language' => $language));
}
```